# Get the critical points and find the máximum or mínimum of $f(x,y,z) = (x^{2} + 2y^{2} +1)\cos{z}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Get the critical points and find the máximum or mínimum of  $f(x,y,z) = (x^{2} + 2y^{2} +1)\cos{z}$

First, I founded the gradient:

$\nabla f(x,y,z)= (2x\cos{z}, 4y\cos{z}, -(x^2 + 2y^2 +1)\sin{z})$

Then:

$$
2x\cos{z} = 0 \\
4y\cos{z} = 0 \\
-(x^2 + 2y^2 +1)\sin{z} = 0
$$

So, the Hessian matrix is:

$
H[f(x,y,z)] = \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
2\cos{z} & 0 & -2x\sin{z} \\
0 & 4\cos{z} & -4y\sin{z}\\
-2x\sin{z} & -4y\sin{z} & -(x^2 + 2y^2 + 1)\cos{z}
\end{array}}\right]$

At this point, I don't know what to do, help me please.

Comment: This function does not have maximum and minimum over $\mathbb R^3$. But  you can find local maximum and local minimum. For the critical points, you have to find all the points $(x,y,z)$ such that $\nabla(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: @Sfarla do you can explain me, for what reason please?

Comment: If you fix $z=0$, then $\cos z=1$ and for $(x,y)\rightarrow \infty$ you have that $f(x,y,0)\rightarrow +\infty$. The same argument, if you fix $z=\pi$, shows that $f(x,y,\pi)\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: However you can find local maximum and local minimum of $f$ by studying the Hessian matrix evaluated in the critical points.

Comment: From the 3rd equation, you have $\sin z=0$ so $z=n\pi$ for some integer n.  From the first 2 equations, you get that $x=0$ and $y=0$ since $\cos z=\pm1$.  Now evaluate the Hessian matrix at these points to identify the local extrema.